# What is maximum length of linkedin social actions batch url?

Tags: java, rest, api, linkedin-api

Linkedin Api provides a batch_get summary for social actions.What is the limit of posts|shares|comments that can be included in the url?
Can i include more than 100 posts?

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions?ids={shareUrn1|ugcPostUrn1|commentUrn1}&ids={shareUrn2|ugcPostUrn2|commentUrn2}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't support LinkedIn API. This question should be asked on their portal